# Were Rudy Giuliani's divergent opinions related to Romania's fighting against corruption clarified?

Tags: united-states, corruption, romania

According to [the Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2018/aug/28/rudy-giuliani-romania-letter-corruption) Rudy Giuliani sent a rather strange letter to Romanian President about some fighting against corruption issues:

> In a letter to Romanian president Klaus Iohannis (..) Giuliani sharply
>   criticised what he called “excesses made in the name of ‘law
>   enforcement’” by Romania’s national anti-corruption directorate. The
>   agency, he said, had used unfair tactics against suspects and
>   intimidated judges and lawyers.
>
> “An amnesty should be given to those who have been prosecuted and
>   convicted through the excesses,” Giuliani said, claiming “many
>   innocent people” had been jailed.

This speech blatantly resembles the speech of some of the politicians in power.

The same article mentions that this letter contradicts what seems to be the official politics of US related to the same issue:

> The state department moved to distance itself from Giuliani’s
>   intervention. Asked if the US agreed with his remarks, a spokesman
>   said: “Romania until recently has shown considerable progress in
>   combating corruption and building effective rule of law. We encourage
>   Romanians to continue on this path.” **The White House did not respond to a request for comment.**

Of course, this letter created some stir in Romania where there have been many protests against current Government, mainly related to anti-corruption law changes.

I am wondering if this divergence was clarified by the White House or not.

**Question:** Was Rudy Giuliani's divergent opinions related to Romania's fighting against corruption clarified?

Comment: Side note: that is particularly interesting in Romania as US has always been seen as a partner when it comes to fighting against corruption. One can see that some anti-government protesters fly US flags (besides EU and Romanian ones).

Comment: One big issue here is that Rudy Guiliani is one of Trump's lawyers, but he is not part of the administration. Formally his opinions have the same relevance as yours. Of course, the fact that he has direct access to Donald Trump makes people wonder if he is voicing the POTUS opinion or he is just using the spotlight to publicize his own opinions. The former may be reinforced by the fact that [he has already done the same before](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/donald-trump/state-department-giuliani-doesn-t-speak-u-s-foreign-policy-n872096) without consequences.

Comment: @SJuan76 - OK, so I expect also nothing to really happen this time. But I am wondering why promote such a strange view? Romania is part of EU and also has a special justice monitoring (CVM). Also, why any US citizen bother about fighting too much the corruption at the other side of NATO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were news reports that Giuliani was [paid for the lobby work](https://www.politico.com/story/2018/08/29/rudy-giuliani-romania-consulting-advocacy-801582), and that it [bewildered policy experts](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/08/31/opinions/giuliani-romania-letter-opinion-ghitis/index.html) in Washington. If one believes the financial angle, that clarifies where it came from.

Comment: Giuliani fights against corrupt/abusive (?) prosecutors somewhere in Eastern Europe. State Department is speechless. Where have seen that again...